# Coffescript: Generate an inline worker from existing class

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, web-worker

I'm making one big Coffeescript application and I want to use web workers.
I don't want to import them from another file so I would like to inline them, but have them written in coffeescript.

Which is the most optimal way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

What I have figured out to this moment is the following:

Having a worker like this one:

```
class LoginWorker 
  #worker with an awesome entry method
  process: (message)=>
    console.log "Processing #{message}"
```

I'm creating a function export object, that uses the method convertToText from http://jsfiddle.net/numoccpk/1/

```
exportObject: (obj)->
    # Gets the constructor implementation and then the prototype
    ctor = convertToText obj
    proto = convertToText obj.prototype

    # Stitch them together, now it looks like a worker file

    text = """
    // Defines the bind function from Coffeescript in order
    // to be able to use ()=> functions.
    var bind = function(fn, me){ return function(){ return fn.apply(me, arguments); }; };
    var worker = #{ctor}
    worker.prototype = #{proto}
    var workerInstance = new worker;
    self.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
      workerInstance.process(e.data);
    }, false);

    """

    # Create a Blob and get its URL
    blobUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL new Blob([text])
    # Build the worker inline!
    worker = new Worker(blobUrl)
```

Then you just need to invoke `exportObject(LoginWorker)`, making sure that `LoginWorker` is available in the scope, of course.